# animate specific sprite with multiple sprite on android using andengine

Tags: android, andengine, sprite

i have multiple objects on my canvas. and after some condition, i want some of my sprite do animate. here my code:

```
private AnimatedSprite[] sign;  
sign = new AnimatedSprite[9];  
// some loop code to create 9 sign  
..  
sign[index] = new AnimatedSprite(x, y, myregion);  
..
```

until this part is ok, all signs is on position. but when i want to animate some sprite, all of that sprite will do animate too. here the code:

```
while(signIndex<9)  
{  
  if(signIndex==winSlot[0] || signIndex==winSlot[1] || signIndex==winSlot[2])  
  {  
    grupSign= null;  
    grupSign= sign[signIndex];  
    grupSign.animate(200, true);  
  }  
    signIndex++;  
}
```

anyone know and can help me how to make only specific sprites do animate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my suggestion you have to use deepCopy() method while you create your animated sprite object. As per the following

```
sign[index] = new AnimatedSprite(x, y, myregion.deepCopy());
```

Advantage of using deepCopy() method is that each time new region will created for your sprite.